# How do I scrape a meta tag's info?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape the info of a couple of meta tags using [Osmosis](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis)

The elements look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="“here's the content!">
```

I saw a video using this:

```
tag: "meta[property='og:title']@content"
```

so I tried it like this:

```
.find('head')
.set({
  description: "meta[property='og:title']@content"
})
```

But it doesn't work on my little project. I really don't know how to do it properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the  element in question, using:

```
var myMeta = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]');
```

Once you have grabbed it, you can access its `content` value with:

```
myMeta.content
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var myMeta = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]');

console.log(myMeta.content);
```

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="here's the content!">
```